# Generating prediction intervals for more than 1 linear model in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, model, lm, predict

I am attempting to generate prediction intervals using the function predict() for a new set of data, but across more than one model that I have generated for a dataset. I am relatively inexperienced at using lapply, but figure it should be helpful in this process:

```
#Calling in my libraries:
library(dplyr)

#Creating dataset:

DNase <- DNase

#Generating models, one for each "Run" in DNAse:
model_dna <- DNase %>% 
  group_by(Run) %>% 
  do(model_dna_group = lm(log(density) ~ log(conc), data = .)) %>%   ungroup()

#Creating a new data set to be used to generate predictions:
new_dna <- as.data.frame(DNase$conc) %>% 
  mutate(conc = DNase$conc * 2) %>% select(conc)

#Attempting to apply predict to these models for a new data frame:
new_dna_w_predictions <- lapply(
                           X = model_dna, 
                           FUN = predict, 
                           newdata = new_dna, 
                           interval = "prediction", 
                           level = 0.9
                          )
```

However, this draws the following error:

Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
object 'model_dna' of mode 'function' was not found

I am not sure how best to structure this lapply function, especially when being used across more than one model. Is there a generally cleaner way to approach this?

Comment: With no test data (that is, `model_dna` and `new_dna` or `DNAse`), we can't test our solutions.  Also, "this draws an error" isn't terribly helpful.  It would be good to know what the error actually is...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated it so the test data should work now!

Comment: do you want to apply the model to every observations of new data? or each model should be applied to a diffent set of rows according to the Runs you are considering?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to run all the "new_dna" data through each of the models separately and generate predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a full `tidyverse` solution:

```r
# Calling in my libraries:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Creating dataset:
DNase <- DNase

# Creating a new data set to be used to generate predictions:
new_dna <- DNase %>% transmute(conc = conc * 2)  # simplified

# Generating models, one for each "Run" in DNAse:
model_dna <- DNase %>% 
  group_by(Run) %>% 
  summarise(model_dna_group = list(lm(log(density) ~ log(conc))))
  
model_dna
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    Run   model_dna_group
#>    <ord> <list>         
#>  1 10    <lm>           
#>  2 11    <lm>           
#>  3 9     <lm>           
#>  4 1     <lm>           
#>  5 4     <lm>           
#>  6 8     <lm>           
#>  7 5     <lm>           
#>  8 7     <lm>           
#>  9 6     <lm>           
#> 10 2     <lm>           
#> 11 3     <lm>


# Run predictions
model_dna %>%
  group_by(Run) %>% 
  summarise(map(model_dna_group, predict, newdata = new_dna, interval = "prediction", level = 0.9) %>% map_dfr(as_tibble),
            .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 1,936 x 4
#>    Run       fit    lwr    upr
#>    <ord>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 10    -2.16   -2.48  -1.85 
#>  2 10    -2.16   -2.48  -1.85 
#>  3 10    -1.33   -1.64  -1.03 
#>  4 10    -1.33   -1.64  -1.03 
#>  5 10    -0.918  -1.22  -0.617
#>  6 10    -0.918  -1.22  -0.617
#>  7 10    -0.503  -0.804 -0.201
#>  8 10    -0.503  -0.804 -0.201
#>  9 10    -0.0873 -0.392  0.217
#> 10 10    -0.0873 -0.392  0.217
#> # ... with 1,926 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Notice:

- after `dplyr` 1.0 you don't need to use `do` anymore for this kind of cases
- with `map` and `map_dfr` you can calculate your predictions and fit them nicely in your `tibble`

Answer (score 1):

Your object `model_dna` is a data.frame (more precisely: a tibble) which contains the `lm`-objects in its second column "model_dna_group".

In the `lapply`-call you should refer to that column, not the whole data frame. Lapply tries to use `predict` on the columns of the data frame instead of the `lm`-objects within the second column.

So edit your call as follows and it works:

```
new_dna_w_predictions <- lapply(
                           X = model_dna$model_dna_group, 
                           FUN = predict, 
                           newdata = new_dna, 
                           interval = "prediction", 
                           level = 0.9
                          )
```